# Getchar function in C

Tags: c

I don't understand the getchar function, or well really how it's laid out. I'm reading K&R and I feel as if it's going a bit too fast.

I understand EOF is end of file with an integer value of -1. Here's a piece of code:

```
#include <stdio.h>
/* copy input to output; 1st version */
main()
{
    int c;
    c = getchar();
    while (c != EOF) {
        putchar(c);
        c = getchar();
    }
}
```

What my current understanding is:
We declare a variable called c that will be an integer, not a character because we can't fill the function with 1 byte only, so we use multiple, and this works because characters in C are stored in memory by their ASCII value(Please correct me if I'm wrong)

As for the while loop, is it there to keep the program running for multiple inputs? So the loop is saying, while variable c is not equal to the end of file we can receive input from getchar() to be fed to c, which we display using putchar(), then, the last c = getchar(); is to stall the program so it doesn't exit immediately?

The next program:

```
#include <stdio.h>
/* count characters in input; 1st version */
main()
{
    long nc;
    nc = 0;
    while (getchar() != EOF)
        ++nc;
    printf("%ld\n", nc);
}
```

As for declaring nc; for a long, why? We used integer before, and now we use long? I understand in some cases, long can store more value than an integer?

Why do we set nc = 0? As for the increment operator, I understand that. Is changing the data type just for demonstration purposes of how we can use different data types to hold potentially large values?

Comment: "c = getchar(); is to stall the program so it doesn't exit immediately?" - no, it's to read the next character to be displayed. This is inside the `while` loop (not very obvious from the way you indent the code, but it is controlled by the position of `{` `}`, not by the indentation)

Comment: In the first, `c` holds the most-recent value returned from `getchar()`, In the second, `nc` is a *counter* of values pulled from `getchar()` which we never cared about an thus never saved anywhere. One holds data returned from a function, the other counts the number of times the loop was iterated. They're entirely unrelated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> As for declaring nc; for a long, why? We used integer before, and now we use long? I understand in some cases, long can store more value than an integer?

Probably because the author of the code wanted to. In this case, it's unlikely to overflow, so the exact size doesn't really matter.

On 32-bit machines, `long` is the same as an `int` (i.e. 32 bits long), while on 64-bit machines, `int` is 32 bits long and `long` is 64 bits long.

> Why do we set nc = 0?

Because otherwise, `nc` contains a garbage value, and incrementing it would be meaningless.

Comment: Why is incrementing useless with a garbage value, what is this garbage value? Is it because it would continuously count the garbage value instead of taking the user input? Thanks everyone for your replies.

Comment: @sbnation In C, a variable's value is indeterminate if you don't ever initialize it. It could be anything.

Comment: @sbnation: To increment a variable it needs to be read first. Reading an uninitialised variable invokes Undefined Behaviour. Conclusion: Incremeting an uninitialised variable implies invoking Undefined Behaviour.